# Equivalent of MPMovieScalingMode in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation, avplayer

With MPMoviePlayerControllers's, scaling a movie is easy with setting MPMovieScalingMode. (like MPMovieScalingModeFill, MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill)

With AVPlayer/AVPlayerLayer I can't seem to find anything like that. Do I have to do this myself? If so, how do I start on this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Take a look at `videoGravity` property in AVPlayerLayer, looks like it is what you need.

Comment: Vladimir was faster than me. In my previous project I used videoGravity for what you intend.

Comment: Thanks! Totally overlooked that! It's a NSString - pretty weird.

Comment: Thanks ! Is there any equivalent of Center content mode ? Didn't find it in AVPlayerLayer.

Answer (score 9):

For some users, you can use `videoGravity` like this :

```
playerViewController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

also :

- AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
- AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
- AVLayerVideoGravityResize